# Retrieve a SPFolderCollection class in descending order

Tags: web-part, sandbox-solution

I have a Sandbox webpart which retrieves a collection of Folders in a Library.

The library contains the following sample data:

```
|   Name        |   Created   |
-------------------------------
|    Folder 1   |  05/06/2013 |
|    Folder 2   |  07/08/2014 |
|    Folder 3   |  05/06/2015 |
|    Folder 4   |  04/03/2016 |
|    Folder 5   |  09/09/2016 |
|    ...        |    ...      |
```

I need retrieve these results ordered by `Created` field.

---

I have the following code for retrieve the collection of folders and sort its results:

```
string ImageLibrary = "GalleryLibrary";

// Get folders in the image library.
SPFolderCollection coleccionAlbums = (SPFolderCollection)_web.Folders[ImageLibrary].SubFolders;
List<SPFolder> spFolders = new List<SPFolder>();

// Create a new List<SPFolder> for store folders in DESCENDING order.
foreach (SPFolder fl in colAlbums) { spFolders.Add(fl); }
```

And I use any of the following code for order the elements in the list:

```
spFolders.Reverse();
// or
spFolders.Reverse(0, spFolders.Count);
```

However, the previous methods order the items by **name**, not by **Date**.

I make this change, but the `Created` property is not found:

```
spFolders.Sort((f1, f2) => f1.Item["Created"].ToString().CompareTo(f2.Item["Created"].ToString()));
```

**How order a List of SPFolder by Created field?**

Comment: SPFolderCollection coleccionAlbums = (SPFolderCollection)web.Folders[ImageLibrary].SubFolders;
              List<SPFolder> spFolders = new List<SPFolder>();

              foreach (SPFolder fl in coleccionAlbums) {
                  if (fl.Item != null)
                  {
                      spFolders.Add(fl);
                  }
              
              }
              spFolders.Sort((f1, f2) => f1.Item.Folder.Item["Created"].ToString().CompareTo(f2.Item.Folder.Item["Created"].ToString()));

Comment: @Prasanna thank you for your comment, but you should post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```
 using System.Linq;
```

Try this:

```
spFolders.OrderByDescending(f => f.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Created]);
```

or this (faster):

```
spFolders.OrderByDescending(f => f.Item.ID);
```

or this:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = @"<Where>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' />
                        <Value Type='Integer'>1</Value>
                    </Eq>
                </Where>
                <OrderBy>
                    <FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='False'/>
                </OrderBy>";

string ImageLibrary = "GalleryLibrary";
SPList list = _web.Lists.TryGetList(ImageLibrary);
if (list == null) return;

List<SPFolder> spFolders = new List<SPFolder>();
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
foreach (SPListItem item in items)
{
    spFolders.Add(item.Folder);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. `List<SPFolder>` doesn't have OrderBy method, but I'm testing a variations of your code and see it if works. I also check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7024474/4092887).

Comment: I changed the answer to make it Descending.add using System.Linq;

Comment: I changed the answer to make it Descending. Add using System.Linq; for the OrderBy method

Comment: Cecilia, I used the CAML Query approach you posted and it worked wonders. Thank you and [Welcome to SharePoint Stack Exchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour).